# List WebElement always selecting first element from the drop-down but i want to select 4th element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

My list has approximate 190 items and items also getting traced one by one in for loop. I applied the condition to a specific text. however, debugger entering into condition but selecting always the first element from the drop-down. In mentioned code country "America" present on the 4th index of my drop-down.

```
List<WebElement> options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='Countryitems_popup']/div[1]/ul//li/span"));
for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++)
{
    WebElement select=options.get(i);
    String innerhtml=select.getAttribute("innerHTML");

    if(innerhtml.contentEquals("America"))
        {
            select.click();
            break;
        }
}
```

HTML is mentioned below:

```
<div id="Countryitems_popup" class="e-scroll e-js e-wid" tabindex="" style="height: auto; display: block;">
    <div class="h-con" style="height: 150px; width: 158.891px;">
        <ul class="H-Kl" role="listbox">
            <li data-value="001" id="004" role="option" unselectable="on" class="">
                <span class=" e-ddltxt">Country 1</span>
            </li>
            <li data-value="676" id="006" role="option" unselectable="on" class="">
                <span class=" e-ddltxt">Country 2</span>
            </li>
            <li data-value="765" id="009" role="option" unselectable="on" class="">
                <span class=" e-ddltxt">Country 3</span>
            </li>
            <li data-value="0067" id="065" role="option" unselectable="on" class="">
                <span class=" e-ddltxt">America</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a `SELECT` dropdown or not? It looks like it's not. Please post the relevant HTML from the dropdown... at least a sampling of it.

Comment: HTML is updated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use for each loop for more readability. Try with this code :

```
List<WebElement> options= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//[@id='Countryitems_popup']/div[1]/ul//li/span"));
            for(WebElement option : options) {
                if(option.getText().trim().equals("America")) {
                    option.click();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

This should work, provided the xpath should be correct.

Comment: Not working, XPath is correct as getting the accurate size of the list element with options.size() method. don't know why its always selecting the first element.

Comment: @AmitSaini : You will have to click on drop down list first using selenium, then the code provided by me should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with selector itself without loop. The xpath to find the list element with text 'America' will be as,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='Countryitems_popup']/div[1]/ul//li[conatins(text(), 'America')]")).click()
```

Comment: Your `click` is missing the parens, `click()`, and you can't click a collection... you are using `.findElements()` with an 's' (plural).

Comment: Thanks. Its typo. Updated

Comment: You missed the `click` fix.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the page to test it, it's hard to know exactly what the issue is but if it's like other pages I've seen you will need to:

1. Click the "dropdown" to open it (and make the options visible)
2. Wait for the desired option to be clickable (indicating the list is open and visible)
3. Click the desired option

My recommendation is to put this all in a method called `selectCountry()` (or something similar) and pass in the desired country name.

```
public void selectCountry(String countryName)
{
     // I'm assuming this is the container for the dropdown. Clicking it should open the dropdown
    driver.findElement(By.id("Countryitems_popup")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='Countryitems_popup']//span[.='" + countryName + "']))).click();
}
```